# drop rows that have duplicated indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where each observation is identified by an `index`. However, for some indices the DF contains several observations. One of them has the most updated data. I would like to drop the outdated duplicated rows based on values from some of the columns.

For example, in the following DataFrame, how can I drop the first and third rows with `index = 122`?

```
index col1 col2
122   -    -
122   one  two
122   -    two
123   four one
124   five -
```

That is, I would like to get a final DF like this:

```
index col1 col2
122   one  two
123   four one
124   five -
```

This seems to be a very common problem when we get data through several different retrievals over time. But I cannot figure out an efficient way of cleaning the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby/transform` to create a boolean mask which is `True` where the group count is greater than 1 and any of the values in the row equals `'-'`. Then you could use `df.loc[~mask]` to select the unmasked rows of `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
count = df.groupby(['index'])['col1'].transform('count') > 1
mask = (df['col1'] == '-') | (df['col2'] == '-')
mask = mask & count
result = df.loc[~mask]
print(result)
```

yields

```
   index  col1 col2
0    122   one  two
1    123  four  one
2    124  five    -
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will drop any `index` that have `col1` equals to `-`. Instead, I only want to drop rows with duplicated indices. Another problem with `transform` is it tends to be really slow with large number of observations.

Comment: Your terminology is unfamiliar to me. What are you taking to be an "indice"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Just think of it as a column that I use to identify each observation. Please see my edited example.

Comment: @unutbu. Thanks for the answer. I accepted it. Just one comment: `transform` takes forever for large data set. One work around is to create another reduced dataset of index count and then join it to `df` to get the `count` column.

Comment: @unutbu, by the way, is there any advantage of using `df.loc[~mask]` instead of `df[~mask]`? The running time seems similar.

Comment: Are you using `df.join(df.groupby(['index'])['index'].count(), rsuffix='_count', on='index')` to avoid `transform`? My tests show this is slightly faster, but not by much. If you are using something else, please post it; I'd love to learn if there is something faster.

Comment: My personal convention is to use `df[...]` for selecting columns, and
`df.loc[...]` for selecting rows. That `df.loc[mask]` is slightly faster than `df[mask]` when mask is a boolean array is gravy on top.

Comment: @unutbu, thanks for your comment on `.loc`. Regarding your question on `transform`, yes that is what I am using. The issue is `.count()` counts `non-NAN` values thus is very slow. Here we should use `.size()`. I test with 10k observations, `df.join(df.groupby(['index'])['index'].agg('size': np.size), on='index')` takes about 0.2 sec. Use `df.join(df.groupby(['index'])['index'].size(), on = 'index')` takes only 0.05 secs (but need to give the series a name first, right?). While `df.groupby(['index'])['index'].transform(np.size)` takes 11 sec.

Comment: @unutbu, by the way, `.count()` takes about 2.5 secs on the same sample. still much faster than `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

If the index is already a column then you can [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) and pass param `take-last=True`:

```
In [14]:

df.drop_duplicates('index', take_last=True)
Out[14]:
   index  col1 col2
1    122     -  two
2    123  four  one
```

if it's actually your index, then you'd be better off calling `reset_index` first and then perform the above step and then set the index back again.

There is a method for `Index` to call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.Index.drop_duplicates) but this just removed duplicates from the index, the returned index with duplicates removed does not allow you to index back into the df with the duplicates removed so I recommend the above approach by calling `drop_duplicates` on the df itself.

**EDIT**

Based on your new information, the easiest maybe to replace the outdated data with `NaN` values and drop these:

```
In [36]:

df.replace('-', np.NaN).dropna()
Out[36]:
       col1 col2
index           
122     one  two
123    four  one
```

**Another Edit**

What you could do is `groupby` the index and take the `first` values of the remaining columns, then call `reset_index`:

```
In [56]:

df.groupby('index')['col1', 'col2'].first().reset_index()

Out[56]:
   index  col1 col2
0    122     -    -
1    123  four  one
2    124  five    -
```

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in my question. I want to drop the row that have outdated data. In the example, I want to drop the row with `col1 = -`

Comment: Are you wanting that as a condition or you want to always take the first duplicated row?

Comment: as a condition. The duplicated row can be in any position and there could be multiple duplicated rows.

Comment: thanks for your edition. But it will drop all rows with `-` values. Instead I only need to drop those that have duplicated `index`. See my edited example, `index = 124` still needs to be kept even though it has `-` values.

Comment: Thanks. But for `index = 122` I would like to get the second row here.